# Not deploying symfony project because the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

Tags: php, symfony, capifony

I will deploy my symfony project of my server with capifony. Capifony is configured to install composer and update the vendors.

When I run `cap deploy` I have this error:

```
     Script Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /home/capepsinfo/www/releases/20140814135415 && php composer.phar update --no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress'\\'''" on capeps.info
```

My deploy.rb:

```
set :application,    "capepsinfo"
set :domain,         "capeps.info"
set :deploy_to,      "/home/capepsinfo/www"
set :app_path,       "/app"
set :web_path,       "/web"
set :user,           "capepsinfo"
set :use_sudo,       false
set :repository,     "ssh://git@github.com/n1c01a5/capeps.git"
set :deploy_via,     :remote_cache
set :scm,            :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, true

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`
set :shared_files,              ["app/config/parameters.yml"]  # next configuration with ssh
set :shared_children,           [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]
set :maintenance_template_path, "web/maintenance.html"

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your `Web` server
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try running it `logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL` to see if you get a bit more detail.

Comment: logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL even done

Comment: and you only get that error?

Comment: no... but this error is too long

Comment: Fix issue to remove `Script Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters` in `composer.json`.